# How to refresh automatically on a PDF viewer?

Tags: pdf, refresh, viewer

I am editing LaTeX on my Windows Vista systems. Which I am using `pdflatex` to generate PDF file constantly.

My PDF viewer is Adobe Acrobat Professional 7, I have to close and open the same file each time to get the new look.

Is there any way to keep the PDF viewer refreshing the PDF pages once it changed?

Comment: Similar question on different sites: [texworks - PDF reader on Linux capable of continuous updating - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28952/pdf-reader-on-linux-capable-of-continuous-updating) ■ [latex - Windows PDF viewer that auto-refreshes PDF when compiling with pdflatex - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/337011/windows-pdf-viewer-that-auto-refreshes-pdf-when-compiling-with-pdflatex)

Answer (score 18):

From [a question on super user](https://superuser.com/questions/337011/windows-pdf-viewer-that-auto-refreshes-pdf-when-compiling-with-pdflatex)

SumatraPDF is free, for Windows, and plays nicely with LaTeX. It will automatically refresh when the pdf is updated.

It's also portable, which is nice.

Comment: Doesn't play along with xelatex unfortunately. The PDF just does not refresh.

Comment: Seems like `SumatraPDF` does not work on Linux or Mac.

Answer (score 15):

The viewer does not regularly check changes on disk, so short answer: no (unfortunately)

You could however, use your browser to see the pdf file, inside your own html 'webpage' that  regularly refreshes the page using javascript.

this is how (including buttons for switching between manual and automatic refreshing):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>my pdf</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       var timer = null;

       function refresh(){
          var d = document.getElementById("pdf"); // gets pdf-div
          d.innerHTML = '<embed src="myPdfFile.pdf" width="700" height="575">';
       }

       function autoRefresh(){
          timer = setTimeout("autoRefresh()", 2000);
          refresh();
       }

       function manualRefresh(){
          clearTimeout(timer); 
          refresh();   
       }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="manualRefresh()">manual refresh</button>
   <button onclick="autoRefresh()">auto refresh</button>
   <div id="pdf"></div>
</body> 
<script type="text/javascript">refresh();</script>
</html>
```

Just save this code as e.g. 'pdfrefresher.html' in the same folder as your pdf. As `src` of the embed object you use only the filename, e.g. 'myPdfFile.pdf' (not disk or directory).
In the code, you can adjust the width and height of the embedded object and the timeout (in milliseconds).

Comment: It's a good solution, however, it keeps refresh the screen.
How can I set it only refresh after changing?

Comment: I'll add a button, moment please

Comment: Done. I put a button to do manual refresh (which is just somewhat easier than re-opening your document in Adobe viewer). Checking for change is another topic; you can perhaps more easily set the timing interval equal to the interval at which your pdf changes?

Comment: For the Linux X11 users: You can create a script that executes in vim OnWrite and sends F5 to the PDF Reader. For Mozilla/Firefox you can use this: https://gist.github.com/sijanec/0f5cbc2d894d74f48df80e35838ac967/5347e67495732f07a50bc508661b9642c18a9a63

Answer (score 7):

Evince pdf viewer auto-refreshes.

It is an extremely light and free (GNU) pdf viewer that is the default on most linux OS. There is a Windows version also. Although, I have used evince only in linux, I am sure it has the same features in Windows.

Comment: Evince 3.30.2 on Linux apparently no longer does this.

Answer (score 4):

Adobe Reader and/or Adobe Acrobat are notorious for not supporting auto-refreshing the view of a PDF which changed on disk.

If you need that, you should switch your viewer.

**[SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/manual.html)** is available for Windows and does auto-refresh the view. Should it not work at times, you can simply type `'r'` to force a refresh...

Answer (score 1):

For Linux desktop systems, [xreader](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/) does an excellent job in the "auto-refresh capable" category. Small number of dependencies; not heavily dependent on any particular desktop (ex: GNOME, KDE) either.

Answer (score 1):

For user who are on MacOS you have  [LivePDFViewer](https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/livepdfviewer/id1477861108?mt=12) that allows you live update of the view and other additional adds like highlighting changes or images zoom.